# MySQLi Extension with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php

I just unpacked the latest phpMyAdmin into /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin and it is giving me "The mysqli extension is missing." - how do I install this? I'm on Centos. I checked php.ini and it seems to be "unlocked".

when I type in php -i |grep -i mysqli ... it looks to be enabled. Also this is PHP Version 5.3.8

```
php -m 

apc
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
memcache
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
posix
REflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
SPL
SQLite
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `it seems to be "unlocked".` mean?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `php -m` ?

Comment: "unlocked" - meant "uncommented", sorry!
 
I'll edit my original post to include php -m (it shows mysqli in php -m but it doesn't show it in my phpinfo.php script...)

Comment: Can you try a simple php script to confirm it's just PMA being goofy? 
`<? mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass'); ?>` then `php -f test.php` and look for errors?

Comment: I haven't set up the db yet so I can't do that, wouldn't my phpinfo.php script rule out that it's not installed?

Comment: If you've only just installed the php-mysql package, then you'll need to restart Apache. Otherwise, check the output of your phpinfo.php script to make sure it's referring to the same `php.ini` file you're looking at.

Comment: You just have to _attempt_ the connection; no DB required. mysqli is clearly installed; but mentioned above - it's possible for apache to utilize a separate php.ini (Debian does it like this)

Comment: Andy, I restarted Apache, same thing. The php.ini is in /etc/php.ini  so that's right.

rovangju, how would I chcek to see which ini apache is looking for? httpd.conf?

Comment: I tried yum install php-mysqli and it give dependencies errors?

Comment: The output from phpinfo(); on a webpage will show the conf location in the first rows of output.

Comment: What are the results of "yum installphp5-mysqli" ? Run phpinfo() either in a PHP page or on the CLI. What does that say about mysqli?

Comment: "no package php5-mysqli is available" - thanks for your comment, I'm hoping to get this straigten out

Answer (score 1):

Install php5-mysql and restart apache. [See why](http://linux.goeszen.com/phpmyadmin-and-mysqli-extension-is-missing-error.html)